# how do I pass my button image to an Image view when its clicked?

Tags: ios, swift, button, uiimage

I think this is a very straight forward process but I'm not clear on the correct syntax for this but here's what I've done so far:

```
@IBOutlet weak var notesImage: UIImageView!

@IBAction func MusicNote(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.sendButtonImage()

}

// This is where the button image is sent to the UIImageView once that specific button is pressed
func sendButtonImage() {
    var note = MusicNote(sender: AnyObject)
```

Comment: Can you show some more of your code? You don't have a `UIButton` declared in this code, I'm assuming that the `sendButtonImage` is called off of the action of that button. Also I'm a little fuzzy on what your trying to do, can you try to explain in more detail?

Comment: apologies for the confusion I'm new to this. I have buttons that are represented by images. I'd like to click the button and pass its image to a separate Image view

Comment: Are your button's `UIImageView` with `TapGestureRecognizers` or are they `UIButton` with a background image set?

Comment: UIButton with a background image set..all of my button work was done in the storyboard

Comment: was the code I posted it able to help?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some rough code, you might need to unwrap some optionals, but the theory should work. I would personally set the images on the buttons in your `viewDidAppear` method or something that is done programmatically. Then use the method `backgroundImageForState` to retrieve the image again. Look at the documentation for UIButton [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/backgroundImageForState:).

```
//Set this in view did appear, ect..
var firstImage = UIImage(named: "image1")
var secondImage = UIImage(named: "image2")
var thirdImage = UIImage(named: "image3")

button1.setBackgroundImage(firstImage!, forState state: UIControlState.SomeState) 
button2.setBackgroundImage(secondImage!, forState state: UIControlState.SomeState) 
button3.setBackgroundImage(thirdImage!, forState state: UIControlState.SomeState) 
//End code that should be in viewDidAppear

func buttonTapped(button1: UIButton?){
  imageView.image = button1.backgroundImageForState(UIControlState.SomeState)!
}
```

Let me know if you need any more help, and don't forget to upvote if you found my post useful, and accept if it helped you solve your problem.